# Facebook wall post response is blank screen in webview stuck in XD_proxy.php

Tags: facebook, webview

1. I'm trying to post on facebook wall from Webview, its showing popup
   to share content but after cancel or post it doesn't get back to
   home share screen or unable to dispose popup window. The same
   implementation is working fine in Browser, but not working in
   Webview.

   After sharing or cancel it should get back to share screen, but it
   doesn't get back to the share screen and stuck in XD_proxy.php auth
   link of facebook

Here's my code.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() { 
    FB.init({appId: "App_id", status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true}); 
};

(function() { 
    var e = document.createElement("script"); e.async = true; 
    e.src = document.location.protocol + "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"; 
    document.getElementById("fb-root").appendChild(e); 
}());   

function streamPublish() {      
FB.ui(
  {
   method: 'stream-publish', 
   display: 'iframe',
   message: 'getting educated about Facebook Connect',
   name: 'Connect',
   caption: 'The Facebook Connect JavaScript SDK',
      description: (
      'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
      'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
      'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
   ),
   link: 'http://www.fbrell.com/',
   picture: 'http://www.fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
   actions: [
        { name: 'fbrell', link: 'http://www.fbrell.com/' }
   ],
  user_message_prompt: 'Share your thoughts about RELL'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you are using the [deprecated "stream-publish"](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/) method and not the [new "feed" method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)? Also, I've never tried this webview thing, but I had the same issue (xd_proxy) with IE7 and it was solved when I added the _App Domain_ field in the App Settings page. Have you tried that?